# Why are random Fourier features non-negative?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-smoothing, feature-engineering, tensorflow, fourier-transform

Random Fourier features provide approximations to kernel functions.  They're used for various kernel methods, like SVMs and Gaussian processes.

Today, I tried using the [TensorFlow implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/kernel_methods) and I got negative values for half of my features. As I understand it, this shouldn't happen.

So I went back to the [original paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/07.rah.rec.nips.pdf), which---like I expected---says that the features should live in [0,1]. But its explanation (highlighted below) doesn't make sense to me: the cosine function can produce values anywhere in [-1,1] and most of the points displayed have negative cosine values.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but would appreciate it if someone can point out what it is.

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the highlighted sentence is wrong (or at least confusing):  $z(x)$ *can* be negative. This isn't a problem because we only care about the inner product of $z$, not $z$ itself.

The "inner product" of $z$ only seemed incorrect when I used this method because I mixed up $z'z$ and $zz'$. Not because $z$ was wrong.